# Android - Why does onItemLongClick(...) return a boolean?

Tags: java, android, onlongclicklistener, long-click

Coming from a Java background I am used to dealing with actions though I'm not really sure why the method requires a boolean is returned and don't fully understand the explanation given on the site: true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

As you may know, the `View` hierarchy in Android is represented by a tree. When you return `true` from the `onItemLongClick()` - it means that the `View` that currently received the event is the true event receiver and the event should not be propagated to the other `Views` in the tree; when you return `false` - you let the event be passed to the other `Views` that may consume it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

I will further clarify this for you, by way of an example.

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

//Do all you stuff here    

return true; // or you can return false;
}
```

- return true means: that the event has been handled. No events will be
  fired after this point.
- return false means: the event has NOT been handled. Any other events 
  to do with this click will still fire.

So, after your **onLongClick()** has fired, if you don't want the regular **onClick()** to fire, then just **return true** from the onLongClick() event.