# Android: better to use a boolean?

Tags: android, methods, boolean

I have a LongClick method that launches a Fragment and is working fine:

```
@Override
public void onItemLongClick(int position, View view) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("itemPosition",position);        
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    DeleteCFragment delCDialog = new DeleteCFragment();
    delCDialog.setArguments(bundle);
    delCDialog.show(fm,"delcardview dialog");
}
```

Is there any speed or other advantage to setting up the method with a boolean like this?

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(int position, View view) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("itemPosition",position);        
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    DeleteCFragment delCDialog = new DeleteCFragment();
    delCDialog.setArguments(bundle);
    delCDialog.show(fm,"delcardview dialog");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: in first case you must have to return boolean value as function rerurning boolean

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230469/android-why-does-onitemlongclick-return-a-boolean

Comment: @Veener Hi, I understand return true versus return false for a boolean.  What I am trying to determine is whether to use the boolean (the second example) or just run the first example shown without a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation says:

return true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html

Comment: yes but the first example shown above runs fine without any boolean.  I am trying to determine whether to use first example without a boolean or the second example with a boolean.

Comment: The API documentation recommends returning boolean so you should follow it.  Option #2.

Comment: If your views has other listeners like onClickListener or onTouchListener, you need to use the boolean return to verify longClick event happens. Otherwise abstract method is ok.

Comment: @Andres Vasquez Agramont Ah, that makes sense.  Answer upvoted and accepted, cheers.